# How do I wire three smart Wifi switches to toggle one another?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, smart-switch

I have three Wifi switches that will be wired into the mains. Is it possible to have them act as a toggle for a set of lights? Ie, one switch turns on, they other two switches also turn on. Similarly, turn another switch off, and they all turn off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is certainly possible, but it depends on the programming of the system controlling the switches, which isn't something we can help you with.

Comment: What make and model are the switches, and are they on the same circuit, or different circuits?

Comment: They are hardwired. The switches are generic, but Tuya compatible. The three switches can be "associated" (ie, linked) via the Tuya software and the toggling works via the app.

However, once a switch other than the one that has initially toggled is physically pressed, it sends the system haywire and all logic in the switching is lost.